# RegularExpression for year/calendar week

Tags: .net, regex, validation

my RegularExpression-skills are in need of improvement. So maybe somebody could help me to get back on track.

**Background**: I have a TextBox where the user can enter a year/week-Combination instead of entering the date.  I'm converting that on serverside to a date instance(last day of that week). Now i have to validate this with a RegularExpressionValidator.

**Format**: An exemplary format could be `10w32` for year 2010 and calendar-week 32. The digit *w* is case-insentive. The weeknumber should be between 1 and 53.
Other valid examples:

```
99w02  -> 1999 week 2
2W53   -> 2002 week 53
2001w1 -> 2001 week 1
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
\d{1,4}[wW](\d|([0-4]\d)|(5[0123]))
```

? (Suitably escaped, of course).

Explanation:

- 1-4 digits
- w or W
- Either a single digit...
- ... or two digits whether the first is 0-4 and the second is any digit
- ... or 5 followed by 0, 1, 2 or 3

It's possible that some of the grouping in the alternation construct is unnecessary - this may work too:

```
\d{1,4}[wW](\d|[0-4]\d|5[0123])
```

... test it to see.

This is completely untested, mind you... unit tests are your friend, along with careful scrutiny.

Use `^` at the start and `$` at the end to force the regex to match the whole string, e.g.

```
^\d{1,4}[wW](\d|[0-4]\d|5[0123])$
```

Comment: First, thank you. But the test fails for f.e. `5w16` and all other valid formats. Checked on http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp and with an ASP.Net-RegularExpressionValidator.

Comment: @Tim: Fixed - the `{1-4}` should have been `{1,4}`