# vb.net converting week to date?

Tags: vb.net, date

I am developing an ASPX VB.NET file.  My assignment is to convert an integer representing week of the year into that end date.  For example, if user selects Week 4 for 2011, I want to get date = 1/22/11.  How do I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you really shouldn't ask here. We can help you in pointing out flaws in logic/syntax -- but it's not very honest on either parties part to do your assignment. Perhaps you have some form of what you've tried (that doesn't work), which we could look at. ;)

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659183/how-do-i-get-the-month-number-from-the-year-and-week-number-in-c/659451#659451

Comment: Dim d = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1).AddDays((4 - 1) * 7)

Comment: No, this is not homework.  I am new to VB.NET though.

Comment: @Magnus, when I use your code above, I get the error: "'DateTime' is a type and cannot be used as an expression."

Comment: Thanks guys.  I figured this out now!
Here's what I did:
         Dim FirstWeekDate As Date
         FirstWeekDate = DateSerial(2011, 1, 1).AddDays((dEndWeek.SelectedValue - 1) * 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747148/convert-calendar-week-to-date) a short while ago. I also have [an answer from J.Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758115/regularexpression-for-year-calendar-week) for a RegularExpressionValidator(if you need one).

Here is what i have to get a date from a week of year:

```
Public Shared Function FirstDateOfWeek(ByVal year As Integer, ByVal weekOfYear As Integer) As DateTime
      Dim jan1 As New DateTime(year, 1, 1)
      Dim daysOffset As Integer = CInt(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek) - CInt(jan1.DayOfWeek)
      Dim firstWeekDay As DateTime = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset)
      Dim curCulture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
      Dim firstWeek As Integer = curCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(jan1, curCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, curCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
      If firstWeek <= 1 Then
          weekOfYear -= 1
      End If
      Return firstWeekDay.AddDays(weekOfYear * 7)
End Function
```

and here is the RegularExpressionValidator, although my format(`07w42` means 42.week in year 2007) differs a little from yours.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="CalWeekFormat" runat="server" 
                                 ControlToValidate="TxtCalWeek" Display="None" EnableClientScript="true" 
                                 ErrorMessage="Enter valid Year/Calendarweek-Format: examplary format '09w23' or '9w23' for year 2009 and week 23" 
                                 style="visibility:hidden" 
                                 ValidationExpression="^\d{1,4}[wW](\d|[0-4]\d|5[0123])$" 
                                 ValidationGroup="VG_SAVE">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Short note: the _GetWeekOfYear_ method of of the _Calendar_ class is not [ISO8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/date_and_time_format.htm) conform. See also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.getweekofyear.aspx).

Comment: Hi Tim, if is this is not a ISO8601 is it still applicable or valid to use as a reference ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class **Week** of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx):

```
Imports Itenso.TimePeriod

Module GetStartOfWeekDemo

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("Week start " & GetStartOfWeek(2011, 4))
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

    Public Function GetStartOfWeek(ByVal year As Integer, ByVal weekOfYear As Integer) As DateTime

        Dim week As Week = New Week(year, weekOfYear)
        Return week.Start

    End Function

End Module
```